# why is foursquare api not returning contact information for a venue?

Tags: api, foursquare

One of our testers found this issue:

This foursquare venue 
  https://foursquare.com/v/whole-foods-market/4a38676cf964a520f49e1fe3

When returned as a result of this url query 
  https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=32.747837,--17158101&radius=250&intent=checkin  [some more parameters including secret key]

Produces a result JSON string which includes the venue, but the array of contact data is completely empty.  The foursquare page for the venue lists the twitter contact and URL contact fields, but the JSON looks like this:
{"id":"4a38676cf964a520f49e1fe3","name":"Whole Foods Market","contact":{},"location"  [more data]

Other venues returned by the search typically have the contact data.  I noticed that this one venue does not have a phone number specified.  Could the API be triggering off of that and null'ing out the entire contact list?

UPDATE:  Here is the complete URL request, with the exception of the ID and KEY values

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=32.747837,-117.158101&radius=250&intent=checkin&limit=50&v=20120502&client_secret=XXX&client_id=YYY&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1f9941735,4bf58dd8d48988d118951735,4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,4d4b7105d754a06376d81259
```

Comment: I can't replicate your behavior, after adding my own secret id and key, changing your longitude to -117.58101, and adding v=20130501.  All I get is an empty array for venue.

Comment: Here is the complete URL used for the query with the exception of ID and KEY (replaced with XXX and YYY below).  I have verified that the original URL does return the expected (wrong) response when pasting it into a browser        https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=32.747837,-117.158101&radius=250&intent=checkin&limit=50&v=20120502&client_secret=XXX&client_id=YYY&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1f9941735,4bf58dd8d48988d118951735,4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,4d4b7105d754a06376d81259

Comment: This may be an issue with our API—I'll send updates if I hear anything back. It may have something to do with the fact that this is associated with a chain on Foursquare.

Comment: in case anyone else is tracking this, the 4SQ folks just told me they are still looking into it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's one of two scenarios: (1) the venue has a twitter name associated with it or (2) the chain that the venue belongs to has a twitter name associated with it. In the case of (2), you'll find the twitter name in the page user object associated with the venue. Foursquare looks for the venue twitter name first, then falls back on the chain twitter name when rendering the user-facing venue page.